# Stirling numbers of the second kind and combinatorics

Tags: proof-writing, stirling-numbers

The definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind that I use is: 
the $S(n,k)$ satisfying
\begin{gather*}\tag{1}
\newcommand{\factF}[2]{#1^{\underline{#2}}}
\newcommand{\factR}[2]{#1^{\overline{#2}}}
x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}S(n,k)\factF{x}{k}.
\end{gather*}

where 
\begin{gather*}\tag{2}
\factF{x}{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x-k).
\end{gather*}

**Lemma 1**
\begin{gather*}\tag{3}
S(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n.
\end{gather*}

**Lemma 2**
The number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ distinct objects into $k$ non-empty unlabelled boxes is 
$$\tag{4}
\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n
$$

> My goal is to prove Lemma 1, that is (3), and what I have is (1). 
>   I see two approaches:
>   (A) direct from (1) (I started with $j$-derivatives evaluated at $0$); or (B) using the question [Combinatorial interpretation of explicit formula for Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531653), that shows Lemma 2, replace it in the r.h.s of (1) and show (3).
>   (C) Prove that the $S(n,k)$ given by (1) are the number of ways to partition a set as in *Lemma 2*
>
> All this computations get complicated, and before investing more time into it, I would like to know if there is some simple trick to handle the problem.

Most of what I have read, start from another definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind, the one equivalent given in Lemma 2. I've not found sources starting from the definition that I gave at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the way I prove it in my class ''Discrete Mathematics'' is to show first directly that the number of surjective mappings from $[n]$ onto $[k]$ is $k!\cdot S(n,k)$.

Second, I prove that the number of surjective mappings from $[n]$ onto $[k]$ is given by 
$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {k \choose i}(k-i)^n$ using inclusion-exclusion. Then you have it.

In view of the first statement, I use the definition that $S(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of the set $[n]$ into $k$ subsets (blocks), where $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: In the first step, do you mean that you use the definition of $S(n,k)$ as per (1) in the question? That is, using $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)x^{\underline{x}}$, you get that  the number of surjective maps from $[n]$ onto $[k]$ is $k!\cdot S(n,k)$?

Comment: Please see my added comment.

Comment: Now I understand, but the question is exactly about the use of another definition. See my last paragraph.