# Probablity of a string containing all characters

Tags: probability

Given a string of length $n$, on the $26$ letters in the English alphabet, what is the probability that it contains all $26$ of the letters?

I was thinking in this direction, (but couldn't reach the answer).

Suppose the original question was given length of string, what is the probability that it contains an `A`, and it would be 1 - (the probability that it doesn't contain an `A`) so

[image]

But I'm unable to extend this idea to multiple characters. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you assume that every letter of the string is a random letter with probability $1/26$?

Comment: Sounds like you need the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: If you absolutely insist on a direct approach (*or perhaps more accurately, a disguised direct approach*), you could also use [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) giving a probability of $26!\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\26\end{smallmatrix}\right\}/26^n$, however stirling numbers often are not expected to be known in an undergraduate course while the inclusion-exclusion approach is.

Comment: @cgss yes, they don't have any dependency on each other.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You are right, I misread the question.  I am going to delete my answer, because I see no easy way of salvaging this type of simple analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the letters are chosen with equal probability, and independently, then the problem is equivalent to : Throw $n$ balls inside $m=26$ urns at random, what is the probability that all urns are non-empty?

The total count (number of strings) is clearly $m^n$. The favorable events are less easy to count, you need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle. The result is given by the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and the explanation is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531653/combinatorial-interpretation-of-explicit-formula-for-stirling-numbers-of-the-sec).

Hence the final result is

$$ p = \frac{m! \, S_{n,m}}{m^n}
$$